# Manga with main character a boy and his sword/blade turns into a woman

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I am looking for a manga where the main hero is a boy and has two swords at the beginning where one of them at present turns into a woman and via dual cultivation the sword upgrades/gets stronger.

Comment: This is a nice overview but it is quite brief. Could you [edit] in anything else at all you remember? [This guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193) has some helpful pointers; remember the more you add the greater the chance is someone will find this for you.

Comment: [Elemental Gelade](https://myanimelist.net/manga/114/Erementar_Gerad) is one of the first to pop up when searching for manga where a woman turns into a sword

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is *Makenshi no Maken Niyoru Maken no Tame no Harem Life*, or *The Cursed Sword Master’s Harem Life*.

The main character wakes up in another world with two swords. After a couple chapters, he learns how to transform one of the swords into a woman.

I just did a quick glance through so I'm assuming he learns how to transform the other one also, since the description for the manga mentions the main character is making a sword harem.

Comment: "*a sword harem"* - Now how did I know that was coming? Sigh...