# Isekai manga where the main character lives with a sword he created that turned into a girl

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I was searching for this manga.

Basically I remember he was playing in a game and creating new weapons, then he receives a message and is transported to a world similar to the game.

He finds a house with a girl, that in reality is one of the swords he created and it's sealing a demon general. After she shows him where the sword is, he extracts it and breaks the seal.

In the end he uses this sword for killing the demon general and saves the girl, near death after sealing it for hundred years. This is all I remember. Right: he sleeps with this sword girl and the morning later he finds a baby girl in the bed.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241935/manga-with-main-character-a-boy-and-his-sword-blade-turns-into-a-woman is a partial match, but he died foiling a robbery.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: @LogicDictates the manga is black and white. The last time i read it has likely 10 chapters or less. Not very much.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots actually is a little too differente. Because 1. The mc isn't an hero, but just likely someone who appear in a forest; 2. He hasn't swords but he finds the swords, like the girl that actually is a sword. And she is already a sword. It's not the mc who trasform them into girls. And actually has only a sword at the moment. It's more slow life/slice of life and comic. Well, still it looks good from the first 3 ch.